# Autocorrelation of daily time-series using acf and pacf plots

Tags: r, arima, autoregressive

I have a time series dataset with daily entries over the past 20 years.

I would like to see whether the series is autocorrelated.

To do so I have done the following>

```
dataset=read.csv(file="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/dataset.csv", head=TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
dataset=diff(dataset)
acf(dataset)
pacf(dataset)
```

From the plots it seems that there is no autocorrelation, however, I'm not sure whether the acf and pacf plots are suitable for my dataset.

What is a suitable test for stock data ?

Comment: May I suggest you do a little research on our site? These questions have appeared many times here and there are many examples of solutions.  Start with the [tag:time-series] tag and narrow your search from there. If you don't find what you're looking for, then I invite you to return here and edit your question to make it less general and more focused.

Comment: @whuber, I have edited the question and have already used google and the stackexchange search bar to find relevant entries but I couldn't.

Comment: You mean like https://www.google.com/search?q=acf+site%3Astats.stackexchange.com?

Comment: yes, I have not found any sources on whether acf and pacf plots are suitable for assessing autocorrelation for stock data.

Comment: Just add "stock" to the Google search.